# JS Regex extract data in parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract data inside *$()* from a string.
My string looks something like that

```
$(123=tr@e:123)124rt12$(=ttre@tre)frg12<>$(rez45)
```

Basically there could be anything inside *$()* and between every *$()*.
But here cannot be any $() inside a $().

This is what I have so far that does not work

```
var reg = new RegExp('\\$\\(.*(?![\\(])\\'), 'g');
var match = reg.exec(mystring);
```

Comment: _"I am trying to extract data inside $() from a string."_ Is the requirement to capture only portion of string inside of "$()"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this one `\\$\\([^(]*\\)`:

```js
var mystring = "$(123=tr@e:123)124rt12$(=ttre@tre)frg12<>$(rez45)"

var reg = new RegExp('\\$\\([^(]*\\)', 'g');

console.log(reg.exec(mystring));
console.log(reg.exec(mystring));
console.log(reg.exec(mystring));
```

You can use `match` to collect all matches of the regex pattern in the string:

```js
var mystring = "$(123=tr@e:123)124rt12$(=ttre@tre)frg12<>$(rez45)"

var reg = new RegExp('\\$\\([^(]*\\)', 'g');

console.log(mystring.match(reg));
```

Comment: That works, thank you. One question though, how do you catch every matches in one call?

Comment: Glad it helps !

Answer (score 3):

To capture everything inside $() use a lazy pattern like this: [`(?:\$\()(.*?)(?:\))`](https://regex101.com/r/AnnF3o/1)

```
const regex = /(?:\$\()(.*?)(?:\))/g;
const str = `\$(123=tr@e:123)124rt12\$(=ttre@tre)frg12<>\$(rez45)`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

PS: It would be favorable to use positive Lookarounds instead of non-capture groups, but JavaScript only supports Lookaheads.

Comment: Nice, the only thing is it repeats the match once with $() once without.

Comment: $0 is the full match with surrounding $(...) and $1 contains just what you want.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to extract data inside $() from a string.

You can use `.split()` with `RegExp` `/\)[^$]+|[$()]/` to split string at `")"` followed one or more characters that are not `"$"` or `"$"`, `"("` and `")"` characters, use `.filter()` to return an array with empty string removed

```js
var mystring = "$(123=tr@e:123)124rt12$(=ttre@tre)frg12<>$(rez45)";

var reg = /\)[^$]+|[$()]/;

var res = mystring.split(reg).filter(Boolean);

console.log(res);
```